# makemigration - Create model and insert data only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I've a model as below:

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    cid = models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=3)

countries = {
"AFG": "Afghanistan",
"ALB": "Albania",
"DZA": "Algeria",
"ASM": "American Samoa",
"AND": "Andorra",
"AGO": "Angola",
"AIA": "Anguilla"
};


for c in countries:
    row = Country(label = countries[c], abbr = c)
    row.save()
```

Now whenever I run the following command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

The first time, it creates the table and populates it. The 2nd, 3rd and so on times, it keeps inserting the same data (It is definitely possible that I will be using the makemigration command many times, so I don't want it to insert it everytime the command is run)

Any way to achieve this? Create and insert once?

Comment: It does not run every time you migrate, it will run each time you start a Django process.

Comment: Oh..that makes it worse...any way to prevent that from happening? I'm seeing something related to `migrations.RunPython` in docs, but having a hard time understanding it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) that create data, these get run once when the migration is applied. This is an example where your data migration is added to the migration that also adds the model

```
from django.db import migrations, models

countries = {
    "AFG": "Afghanistan",
    "ALB": "Albania",
    "DZA": "Algeria",
    "ASM": "American Samoa",
    "AND": "Andorra",
    "AGO": "Angola",
    "AIA": "Anguilla"
}


def create_countries(apps, schema_editor):
    Country = apps.get_model('myapp', 'Country')
    for c in countries:
        Country.objects.create(label=countries[c], abbr=c)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0000_previous'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Country',
            fields=[
                ('cid', models.SmallAutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('label', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('abbr', models.CharField(max_length=3)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(create_countries),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out. This was the line I was struggling with - `Country = apps.get_model('myapp', 'Country')` wasn't sure how to include the model